# How do I import helper files (.py) from another python script?

Tags: python, importerror, jetbrains-ide, helper

I am brand new to working with python so this question might be basic. I am attempting to import five helper files into a primary script, the directory setup is as follows and both the script I'm calling from and the helper scripts are located within src here in this path-

```
/Users/myusername/Desktop/abd-datatable/src
```

I am currently importing as-

```
import helper1 as fdh
import helper2 as hdh
..
import helper5 as constants
```

The error I see is

```
  File "/Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/22.77756/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I have also attempted the following for which the import was still unsuccessful:

```
import src.helper1 as fdh
..
import src.helper5 as constants
```

and

```
from src import src.helper1 as fdh
...
from src import helper5 as constants
```

and tried adding the following to the head of the script-

```
import sys
import os

module_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
```

Would be very grateful for any pointers on how to debug this!

Comment: Please edit your question to show the directory structure you have in place for this code.

Comment: Hi, directory set up there as Users/myusername/Desktop/abd-datatable/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems likely that it's a path issue.

In your case, if you want to import from `src`, you would need to add `Users/myusername/Desktop/abd-datatable` to the path.

`os.getcwd()` is getting the path you invoke the script from, so it would only work if you are invoking the script from `Users/myusername/Desktop/abd-datatable`.